# IIS turning off Windows authentication every time we redeploy the site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication, iis-8

Every time I deploy a basic ASP.NET MVC site to one of our intranet servers, the authentication mode for the site and any sub sites turns off. We have it set to Windows. This does not happen to a second server that we use.

This is what we have in our root `web.config` file. We can go in to IIS Manager and turn Windows authentication back on, but why does it get turned off each time even though the config file is set to use Windows authentication?

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <httpModules />
</system.web>
```

Comment: How does your site get deployed? Is it overwriting the web.config?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Yes

Comment: Then you need to make it not overwrite web.config (at least not blindly). How are you deploying your site?

Comment: Our process is to "publish" to a folder and then IT copies the files to the final server location. We do transforms in the config to accommodate certain server specifics.

Comment: The web.configs are identical when deployed but it is defined in our process that we copy all files needed. Would love to use some sort of CI system but that is out of my hands.

Comment: You can try the answer below. Specifically disable anonymous authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add the below section in your web.config file.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security >
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Or you could directly modify the **applicationhost.config** file which is located at **C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config**

```
<location path="TestSite">
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Note: path="TestSite" use your site name in this section and add this code before the `</configuration>` tag.